# How can I add a class to the selected element on click event with select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

We are using Select2 version 4.0.0-rc2

To improve mobile usage we would like to implement adding a class to the clicked item in the drop down.

I tried reacting to the select2 events like this:

```
  element.select2({}).on('select2:open', function(){
     this.addClass('my-class');
  }
```

However, the problem with this is that 'this' is the  option and not the rendered select li. I believe 'this' is because Select2 delegates/passes the event down to the select option.

I also tried directly targeting the result item like this:

```
$('.select2-results li ["aria-selected=true"]').on('click', function(){
    this.addClass('my-class');
}
```

But I get the same problem as above. 'This' and even Event.target are  option.

I found some suggestions from older versions of select2 and tried this:

```
  element.select2({}).on('select2:open', function(e){
     $('.search-results li [aria-selected=true]').on('mouseup', function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     this.addClass('my-class');
  }
```

This one only seemed to work on the second click. So, I clicked to open the list, I select an item, nothing happens, I select another item, it then gets the class.

- Note: Some of the selectors above may not be accurate but its just to give an example. All of my code worked except that I couldnt get my event to fire on the right element.

Could anyone suggest a fix?

Alternatively, on the Select2 page (https://select2.github.io/options.html) , they suggest that in version 4 you can write plugins using an adapter. Im not familiar with adapters and can only assume they mean the adapter pattern? I dont understand how I would even start with this. I understand the concept, I write a wrapper so that my functions are called and I can modify them and also pass through to the library methods? If anyone could provide any further info on how I could do that, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Smells like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the end goal after the class is added? Why are you calling `preventDefault` on the `mouseup` event?

Comment: @KevinBrown after your comment about it being an XY problem I went back to the designer who asked for this and discussed the problem again. I mistakenly thought it was actually more severe but apparently its so that we can put a background highlight on the selected item after you click it and before the drop down closes. Also, apparently one of our other devs also got the mousdown event firing on the li so maybe we have resolved it.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know how to add a specific class to selected ìtems but you can use the `[aria-selected=true]` CSS selector to customize their style.

```
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand how using tags helps? We don't want to use tagging, we want to add a class to the selected item.

Comment: I'm fairly certain nothing to do with tags was mentioned in this question. Perhaps you meant to put this on a different question?

Comment: Sorry, you were right, I misread the documentation. Tagging has nothing to do with your need (I edited my answer). But despite everything, using `[aria-selected=true]` selector is a way to add specific styles to selected items ...

Answer (score -1):

For our case where we wanted to adjust it for mobile touch, we managed to get it working with this code. Note the 'tap' event is provided by jQuery mobile:

```
element.select2({}).on('select2:open', function(e){
 $('.search2-results li').on('tap', function(e){
     $(e.target).addClass('my-class');
 }
}
```